# How to create dynamic attributes on javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, element

I want to know how I can set new attributes for an object previously created.
I tried a looping but didn't work.
In this example the object is set manually.

```
var playlist = [    
{   
url : "07_All_The_Young_Dudes.mp3",
title : "All the young dudes"
},
{   
url : "burn.mp3",
title : "Burn"
},
]
```

Sorry, I will explain better. My system allow people to publish their musics. Everthing is done with php. But I'm using javascript to turn possible play music in mobile phone too. So, there are two arrays generated in PHP: `$url` and `$title` I did the following code in javascript:

```
var thestring = "<?php echo $url;?>"; var spliter = thestring.split('|'); var thestring2 = "<?php echo $title;?>"; var spliter2 = thestring2.split('|'); var i;
var url = [];
var title = [];
var playlist = [        
        {         
            url :'',
            title :''
        },
        ];
```

And put this looping:

```
for(i =0; i < spliter.length;i++){              
    playlist.url[i] = spliter[i];
    playlist.title[i] = spliter2[i];    
}
```

Unfortunately this looping isn't working for me.

Comment: Could you show the looping code you said didn't work and tell us exactly what happened?

Comment: what's the attribute you like to set?

Comment: Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers, I had solved it on my own. 
I modified the looping like this:
`for(i =0; i < spliter.length;i++){

    url[i] = spliter[i];
    title[i] = spliter2[i];

}`
And then I used that vars, solved it all.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean to add an object to the Array, do this.

```
playlist.push({   
    url : "07_All_The_Young_Dudes.mp3",
    title : "All the young dudes"
})
```

If you meant to add a property to an object in the Array, select the object by index, and add it like this.

```
playlist[0].newProperty = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to add attributes dynamically, like this

```
previousCreatedObj.newAttr = [];

previousCreatedObj.another = 2
```

Or, if your object is and array just add an index. `previousCreatedObj[0].yetAnother = 1`

To add items to an array use push

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

```
playList[0].favBeverage = "beer";
```